# XCode 6.1 run on iPhone4/4S

Tags: xcode

I don't manage to run from XCode 6.1 directly on my iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S testdevices. On my other devices (iPhone 6, various iPads) it works fine. but if I connect the iPhone 4 or 4S and hit 'run', the top bar states 'running myapp on mydevice' but nothing happens on the device, also doesn't install it, and then after a while the top of xcode states 'finished running myapp on mydevice' - but nothing happened.

Comment: Which iOS version are you targeting?

Comment: I'm targeting 7.1 and the iPhone 4 runs on 7.1.2 that can't be the issue - if the iphone version would not match xcode would give me an error that the app can't be run on this device - but i'm not getting any error. it states ' running app on device' and then after a while 'finished running app on device' without anything having happened